# React .scrollLeft cannot be reading null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scrollbar

I am trying to access the horizontal scroll bar with buttons in react but turns out it is not working because of error that cannot read the null values of `.scrollLeft`.

```
<>
  <div className="containerOuterSider">
    <FaAngleLeft className= "FaAngleLeft" onClick={slide('left')}/>
    <div id="container3" className="container3">
      {products &&
        products
          .map((product) => (
            <AAsOfLowNav key={product._id} product={product} />
          ))
          .reverse()}
    </div>
      <FaAngleRight className="FaAngleRight" onClick={slide('right')}/>
  </div>
</>
```

and the main function is

```
function slide(direction) {
  var container = document.getElementById('container3');
  let scrollCompleted = 0;
  var slideVar = setInterval(function() {
    if (direction === 'left') {
      container.scrollLeft -= 10;
    } else {
      container.scrollLeft += 10;
    }
    scrollCompleted += 10;
    if (scrollCompleted >= 100) {
      window.clearInterval(slideVar);
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

The error I am facing is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'scrollLeft')
> at LowerCatNav.js:31:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollLeft')
> at LowerCatNav.js:33:1

How can I make it right? Should I use the hooks or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

You are immediately invoking the `slide` function while rendering:

```
<FaAngleLeft
  className="FaAngleLeft"
  onClick={slide('left')} // <-- immediately invoked when rendered
/>
...
<FaAngleRight
  className="FaAngleRight"
  onClick={slide('right')} // <-- immediately invoked when rendered
/>
```

The React component hasn't been fully rendered and pushed to the DOM, so queries to the DOM, i.e. `document.getElementById('container3')`, return `null`.

## Solution

Fix the click handler so `slide` is ***not*** being immediately invoked.

```
<FaAngleLeft
  className="FaAngleLeft"
  onClick={() => slide('left')} // <-- asynchronously invoked when clicked
/>
...
<FaAngleRight
  className="FaAngleRight"
  onClick={() => slide('right')} // <-- asynchronously invoked when clicked
/>
```

It is considered a React anti-pattern to directly query the DOM for DOMNodes, use a React ref for this.

Example:

```
...

const containerRef = React.useRef(); // <-- (1) create Ref
const sliderTimerRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // clear any running intervals on component unmount
    clearInterval(sliderTimerRef.current);
  };
}, []);

...

function slide(direction) {
  // clear any previously set intervals and reset scrollCompleted
  clearInterval(sliderTimerRef.current);
  let scrollCompleted = 0;

  sliderTimerRef.current = setInterval(function() {
    const container = containerRef.current; // <-- (3) access current ref value

    if (direction === 'left') {
      container?.scrollLeft -= 10; // <-- (4)  Optional Chaining null check
    } else {
      container?.scrollLeft += 10; // <-- (4)  Optional Chaining null check
    }
    scrollCompleted += 10;
    if (scrollCompleted >= 100) {
      clearInterval(sliderTimerRef.current);
    }
  }, 50);
}

...

return (
  <>
    <div className="containerOuterSider">
      <FaAngleLeft className="FaAngleLeft" onClick={() => slide('left')}/>
      <div
        ref={containerRef} // <-- (2) attach ref to element
        id="container3"
        className="container3"
      >
        {products
          .map((product) => (
            <AAsOfLowNav key={product._id} product={product} />
          ))
          .reverse()
        }
      </div>
      <FaAngleRight className="FaAngleRight" onClick={() => slide('right')}/>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `slide` is called when `#container3` is not yet created.
   Change `onClick={slide(...)}` to `onClick={() => slide(...)}`
2. Access to global elements (e.g. by id) should be avoided.
   Prefer [`ref`/`createRef`/`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to access elements belonging to your component.